# How to prevent a TTS(Text to Speech) to start reading immediately after opening the activity?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I used a tts for reading my text view,but as soon as i open the activity, it start reading, but i don't want it like this, i want to press the button then it start reading, here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button buttonSpeak;
private Textview tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    buttonSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv= (Textview) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    buttonSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }  });}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();    }

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            buttonSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();     } } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }}
private void speakOut() {
    String text = Textview.getText().toString();
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);  }}
```

Comment: maybe could call stop when onResume

Comment: @Amirhosein I just found the way, I should remove speakout(); from onInit block.

Answer (score 0):

Call speakOut(); from onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
buttonSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
tv= (Textview) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

speakOut();

}
```

Comment: as you see i did it before, in setOnclicklistenrer i did it, it is in onCreat part

Comment: Yes... but you did this inside Button click event. that means when you click button then speakOut() is execute.

Comment: I found the way , I should remove speakout(); from onInit block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call speakout() from inside onInit().